# Scraping <li> from an array of <ul> when some of the <ul> have no <li> children

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm attempting to web scrape data, some of which are `<li>` elements. I think the problem is that some of the `<ul>` parents have no `<li>` children.

A sample of the HTML is this -=

```
<div class="tab-pane predefined-carrier-DPDUK ">
    <img src="https://assets.easypost.com/assets/images/carriers/dpd-logo.c4b107116e903920a5794e69e1990827.svg" alt="DPD UK">
    <ul>
        <li>Parcel</li>
        <li>Pallet</li>
        <li>ExpressPak</li>
        <li>FreightParcel</li>
        <li>Freight</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane predefined-carrier-ChinaEMS ">
    <img src="https://assets.easypost.com/assets/images/carriers/china-ems-logo-ca.0c938786bd8d8f141e8fa9337a3362a4.png" alt="EMS">
    <p>No predefined packages for EMS.</p>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane predefined-carrier-Estafeta ">
    <img src="https://assets.easypost.com/assets/images/carriers/estafeta-logo-ca.886242ba90c68a1d68f0e4e5a3a14419.png" alt="Estafeta">
    <ul>
        <li>ENVELOPE</li>
        <li>PARCEL</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So some of the `<ul>` will return no results, i.e. no `<li>` children. I've come up with a couple of 'solutions'

This one is supposed to iterate through each `<ul>` but it always fails the second `try` so returns no `<li>`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#parcels", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
c = r.content

soup= BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

all = soup.find_all("div", {"class":lambda L: L and L.startswith("tab-pane predefined-carrier")})

for item in all:
    print("\n".join([img['alt'] for img in item.find_all('img', alt=True)]))   
    
    try:
        print(item.find("p").text)
    except:
        print("HAS PACKAGES")
    
    try:
        for ul in all.find_all("ul"):
            for litag in ultag.find_all("li"):
                print(litag.text)
    except:
        print("has no list items")
    
    print("")
```

The result set is this :

```
DPD UK
HAS PACKAGES
has no list items

EMS
No predefined packages for EMS.
has no list items

Estafeta
HAS PACKAGES
has no list items
```

The second solution is this which does return the `<li>` but I cannot figure a way to get each `<li>` to print on a new line:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#parcels", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
c = r.content

soup= BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

all = soup.find_all("div", {"class":lambda L: L and L.startswith("tab-pane predefined-carrier")})

for item in all:
    print("\n".join([img['alt'] for img in item.find_all('img', alt=True)]))   
    
    try:
        print(item.find("p").text)
    except:
        print("HAS PACKAGES")
    
    try:
            print(item.find_all("ul")[0].text)
    except:
        pass
    print("")
```

The result set is similar to this:

```
DPD UK
HAS PACKAGES
ParcelPalletExpressPakFreightParcelFreight

EMS
No predefined packages for EMS.


Estafeta
HAS PACKAGES
ENVELOPEPARCEL
```

Hoping someone can set me on the right path, TIA

Comment: looks like misspelling the first one should be `for ul in item.find_all("ul"):`

Comment: Thank for the reply, I tried that but then get  the data returned like this:  

>    DPD
>No predefined packages for DPD.
>  Talk to support 
>  Contact sales 
>
>DPD UK
>HAS PACKAGES
>  Talk to support 
>  Contact sales 
>
>EMS
>No predefined packages for EMS.
>  Talk to support 
>  Contact sales

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. I have tried to extract the `<ul>` and check if it has `<li>` tags in it. Only then I am printing those `<li>` content on a new line.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#parcels", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
c = r.content

soup= BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

div_tag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":lambda L: L and L.startswith("tab-pane predefined-carrier")})

for i in div_tag:
    uls = i.find('ul')
    # Checks if <ul> is empty. That is no <li> tags present
    if uls.text != '':
        # Gets all the <li> from <ul>
        li_tags = uls.findAll('li')
        # print the text of <li> one after other in new line
        for item in li_tags:
            print(item.text)
        print('\n')
```

```
Sample Output:

Parcel
Pallet
ExpressPak
FreightParcel
Freight

ENVELOPE
PARCEL

Parcel
Satchel
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! It works well as a standalone but when I insert it into my `for item in all:` code block, I get  `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'`

I changed the first line in your code to `for i in item:` which is when I get the above error. If I change it to ` for i in all:`, I get all the `<li>` listed for all the items in the all variable